# mkey of a File on AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a file from AWS using TransferManager. Can someone please suggest how can one find the mkey(required as one of the parameters in the download() function) of a File. In the AWS S3 Document(http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/mobile/sdkforandroid-dev.pdf), it says mkey is the key of the File. But I am not sure How can this value be obtained.

Thanks,

Code:

```
Download download = transferManager.download(BUCKET_NAME, mkey, file);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked:

```
Download download = transferManager.download(BUCKET, "temp/Img1.jpg", file);
```

(None of "temp", "temp/Img1", "Img1", "Img1.jpg" worked.)

Answer (score 0):

mkey is the identifier of the object stored under a bucket. It's equivalent to a file name on your local storage. Since you want to upload a file, so you have to give it a name (mkey in S3), basically anything you want to name it. You will address the file on S3 by bucket name and key name. See S3's documentation for more details. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#BasicsKeys

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am still having doubt. Let's say Image files(Img1.jpg, Img2.jpg ...) are stored inside the 'temp' folder inside a bucket 'BUCKET'. So, what should the code be like ? Download download = transferManager.download(BUCKET, "temp", file);

Comment: Following worked: Download download = transferManager.download(BUCKET, "temp/Img1.jpg", file);

Answer (score 0):

S3 is basically a key/value store, separated by buckets.  So mKey in this example is just whatever the key of your object in S3 is.  Within a single bucket, there can only be 1 object with the same key.  So in you were to upload multiple files with the same key, they would overwrite each other.  Similar to the key in a hashmap.

Let me know if you are still having trouble!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am still having doubt. Let's say Image files(Img1.jpg, Img2.jpg ...) are stored inside the 'temp' folder inside a bucket 'BUCKET'. So, what should the code be like ? Download download = transferManager.download(BUCKET, "temp", file);

Comment: Following code worked:

Download download = transferManager.download(BUCKET, "temp/Img1.jpg", file);